# Cannot find some lunar SDK validation layers

Tags: c++, linux, sdk, vulkan

I am manually checking for the underlying layers wrapped by      `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation`

The wrapper is found, however some of the validation layers it should wrap according to the [documentation](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/view/1.0.13.0/windows/layers.html) are not.

I am querying the layers like this:

```
const std::vector<const char*> validationLayers =
{
    "VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_limits",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation",
    "VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain",
    "VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects",
};

void PrintLayerStatus(VkLayerProperties layer_info, string layer_name, bool layer_found)
{
    string major = to_string(VK_VERSION_MAJOR(layer_info.specVersion));
    string minor = to_string(VK_VERSION_MINOR(layer_info.specVersion));
    string patch = to_string(VK_VERSION_PATCH(layer_info.specVersion));
    string version = major + "." + minor + "." + patch;

    string mark = (layer_found) ? string(CHECK) : string(CROSS);
    RecordLog("\n" + string(layer_name) + ", "
        "Vulkan version " + version + ", "
        + "layer version " + to_string(layer_info.implementationVersion),
        "[" + mark + "]", 77, '.');
    if(layer_found) RecordLog("\tDescription:", string(layer_info.description), 20);
}

// Find available validation layers
bool CheckValidationLayerSupport()
{
    // Query validation layers currently isntalled
    uint32_t layerCount;
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, nullptr);
    std::vector<VkLayerProperties> availableLayers(layerCount);
    vkEnumerateInstanceLayerProperties(&layerCount, availableLayers.data());

    RecordLogHeader("Requesting Vulkan validation layers\t ["
        + to_string(layerCount) + "]");

    RecordLog("Layer", "Found Status", 80-12);
    RecordLog(SEPARATOR_BAR);
    // Check needed validation layers against found layers`
    for (const char* layerName : validationLayers)
    {
        bool layerFound = false;
        VkLayerProperties layer_info;
        for (const auto& layerProperties : availableLayers)
        {
            if (strcmp(layerName, layerProperties.layerName) == 0)
            {
                layerFound = true;
                layer_info = layerProperties;
                break;
            }
        }

        PrintLayerStatus(layer_info, layerName, layerFound);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Which produces the output:

```
================================================================================
Requesting Vulkan validation layers      [16]
================================================================================

Layer                                                               Found Status
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1............[✓]
        Description:       Google Validation Layer

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1.[✓]
        Description:       LunarG Validation Layer

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_limits, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1........[✗]

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1.......[✓]
        Description:       LunarG Validation Layer

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1................[✗]

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1......[✓]
        Description:       LunarG Validation Layer

VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1............[✗]

VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects, Vulkan version 1.1.92, layer version 1.......[✓]
        Description:       Google Validation Layer
```

I also ran vulkaninfo with grep to see if I could find those layers for example

`vulkaninfo | grep VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image`

All of them return empty, so it seems I did not properly install the SDK or I did something wrong.

My installation was simply downloading the sdk and linking against the include directory plus running the setup-env.sh script (I do this each time prior to compilation). I am not sure If I have accidentally skipped a step, like running a script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using old documentation. At the time of writing latest SDK version is 1.1.101.

Per the [doc](https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.1.101.0/windows/getting_started.html) `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation` consists of:

1. `VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_threading`
2. `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation`
3. `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_object_tracker`
4. `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation`
5. `VK_LAYER_GOOGLE_unique_objects`

These seem to check out per your output.

Of course this may (and did) change over time:

`VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_limits` was merged with `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` and `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_parameter_validation` in SDK 1.0.21.

`VK_LAYER_LUNARG_image` was merged with `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` in SDK 1.0.42.

`VK_LAYER_LUNARG_swapchain` was merged with `VK_LAYER_LUNARG_core_validation` in SDK 1.0.51.

Update: in 1.1.106 `VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation` is indroduced, and all of the above gets deprecated.

Comment: Awesome, at least I can now just delete those lines and move on!